# Microsoft ISA Server Authentication in Android

Tags: java, android, security, ntlm

I have an application in Android, in which I were reading files from the remote server, code for reading file is given below;

```
            URI uri = null;
            try {
                uri = new URI("http://192.168.1.116/Server1/Users.xml");
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
            httpget.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            httpget.setHeader("host", "192.168.1.116");

            HttpResponse response = null;
            try {
                response = httpClient.execute(httpget);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
            String result = null;
            try {
                result = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
                Log.d("SERVER1", result);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Now all the remote files are behind proxy (Microsoft ISA Server) which required authentication to access the files. Please guide me how I can pass authentication parameters from android to access the files.

I have tried the following codes but useless,

```
           URL uri = null;
            try {
                uri = new URI("http:// 192.168.1.116/CookieAuth.dll?Logon");
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

             DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpclient.getCredentialsProvider()
                    .setCredentials(
                            AuthScope.ANY,
                            new NTCredentials(username, password, deviceIP,
                                    domainName));

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri);
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("curl", "Z2FServer1/users.xmlZ2F"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("formdir", "3"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "test"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "test"));

            UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = null;
            try {
                ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            httppost.setEntity(ent);
            try {
                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                Log.i("Test", response.getStatusLine().toString());

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                if (entity != null) {

                    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                    result = convertStreamToString(instream);
                    Log.d("ISA Server", result);

                    instream.close();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

But it’s giving `HTTP1.1` 500 Internal Server Error. I have also tried following link but same error
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/10937857/67381

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case i use

```
public static DefaultHttpClient getClient(String username, String password,
        Integer timeOut) {
    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, timeOut);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, timeOut);
    DefaultHttpClient retHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
    if (username != null) {
        retHttpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
    }

    return retHttpClient;
}
```

Try, may be works.

P.S.

It's not for ISA, for MS C# WebService Application, but maybe...

Comment: I am getting HTTP/1.1 500 (Unspecified Error).